# How do I use Sanity Studio v3 in a PnPM monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, sanity, pnpm

I am testing out Sanity Studio v3 for the first time.  In the past (v2), I was able to get Sanity and my frontend (Sveltekit or Next) set up in a simple PNPM monorepo so I only need to run one command to start everything and do other common tasks.

The monorepo I am using is [here](https://github.com/WebRuin/monorepo-starter).  This is a demo, but is will show you the basic inter workings.

The problem I am having is that I do not seem to have the ablity to start sanity sudio in dev mode from the root packack.json.  Here are my scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:sveltekit": "pnpm -F @sanity-3-playground/sveltekit dev",
  "start:sanity": "pnpm -F @sanity-3-playground/sanity pnpm dev",
  "start": "pnpm -r start",
  "update:all": "pnpm -r update -i -L",
  "clean": "find ./ -name node_modules -type d -exec rm -rf {} +"
},
```

Here are the scripts in the Sanity package.json:

```
"dev": "sanity dev",
  "start": "sanity start",
  "build": "sanity build",
  "deploy": "sanity deploy",
  "deploy-graphql": "sanity graphql deploy"
```

When I `pnpm start` from the sanity dir every this is great,  but when I run `pnpm start:sanity` in the root folder, I get

```
  IMPORTANT: You're running Sanity Studio v3, and in this version 
  the [start] command is used to preview static builds. To        
  run a development server, use the [npm run dev] command instead.
                                                                   
  For more information go to https://www.sanity.io/help/studio-v2-vs-v3
```

I can see that it wants me to hit enter to enter dev mode, but it does not work.

Comment: "start:sanity": "pnpm -F @sanity-3-playground/sanity pnpm dev" -> you don't need to add pnpm again in the script. So try "start:sanity": "pnpm -F @sanity-3-playground/sanity dev"

Comment: I have... same thing